# Less: class then node type

Tags: less

I have two `<p>` and one `<button>` that extend a certain `class` named `test`. I want to know if it is possible to add certain style rules to `.test` and then specific rules for the element type?

I thought of something like this:

```
.test {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: blue;

    &p {
        font-size: 26px;
    }

    &button {
        font-size: 20px;
    }
}
```

I know it is impossible to write it like that. This example is only for a concept example.

I've read the documentation and alas i found nothing...

Any idea or is this just impossible to achieve?

Comment: [Changing Selector Order](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature-changing-selector-order). [Example](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22.test%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20font-weight%3A%20bold%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20color%3A%20blue%3B%5Cn%5Cn%20%20%20%20p%26%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20font-size%3A%2026px%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%5Cn%20%20%20%20button%26%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20font-size%3A%2020px%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%22%7D).

Comment: That example is perfect!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you should use `:extend`:

**LESS:**

```
.test {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: blue;
}

p:extend(.test) {
  font-size: 26px;
}

button:extend(.test){
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

**Output:**

```
.test, p, button {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: blue;
}
p {
  font-size: 26px;
}
button {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Could `.test` extend `p`?

Comment: Yes you can do `.test:extend(p)` and .test get the properties of `p`

Comment: Which wouldn't be useful since I want `p` to get `.test` properties and not the opposite. Am I getting this right?

Comment: that's what I put in my answer or I don't unterstand you.